# poco classes setting default value from another entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
public class Price
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        // Set default value here
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int PriceId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

I've searched in the internet the best way to set a default value in a field. They say put in the `constructor` or make a `backing field`. Now what if I want to set a default value in an entity from another entity's field value? Say, the default value of `Product`'s `Price` is the latest `Price`(in the Price class)

How do you achieve that?

`Price = Context.Price.FirstOrDefault().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)`?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You want to query your DB inside the `Product` constructor for the latest price? or is `Context` another property of `Product`?

Comment: Yes. I want to get the latest price in the DB and set it in the `Product`'s `Price`. My bad, Context is just my `DbContext`.

Comment: Another one, Is it the best approach of doing so?

Comment: When do you need this value? Coupling your POCO objects with your Data Access Layer is a bad design

Comment: I guess you're right. But what I want is pretty simple, when I get a `Product` from DB, I want the value of `Product.PriceId` to be the latest value in the `Price` class. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would do is when i query the DB to return the `Product` / `Products`, i would let it fill the price for me.

*This is a just for demonstration purposes*

I would do something like:

```
public class MyDataAccessLayer
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return DbContext.Products.Select(x => new Product 
        { 
            Price = Context.Price.FirstOrDefault().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
        };
    }

    public Product GetProduct(string id)
    {
        var product = DbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        if (product != null)
        {
           product.Price = Context.Price.FirstOrDefault().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id);
        }

        return product;
    }
}
```

I would definitely let me `Data Access Layer` do the fetching for me and have it fill the latest price from the DB, and **not** have the POCO access my database.

Answer (score 1):

Keep last inserted `Product`e in `Cache`. while you are creating new `Product` get last `Product` from `Cache` and set default values inside constructor and when you are inserting new `Product` update `Cache`.
While you are inserting new Product it's same as getting last Product from database because new inserted product is last product in database. So instead of:

```
var lastProduct = Context.Products.FirstOrDefault().OrderByDescending(c => c.Id);
```

do this:

```
var lastProduct = Context.Products.Add(newProduct);
Cache.Set("LastProduct", lastProduct, new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0)});
```

There are some advantages here. first you dot query database every time for getting last product. second your are not going access EF Context inside your Poco class.

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        // var lastProduct = (Product)Cache["LastProduct"];
        // Set default value here
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public int PriceId { get; private set; }

    public virtual Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I want the value from the DB. Such a query `SELECT top 1 Price FROM Price ORDERBY Id DESC`

Comment: Will the Cache expire?

Comment: After 1 year if no new product have been created. you can set the time depends on your needs.

Comment: Thanks mate. What other approach do you have in mind? I would like to hear it.